# add and remove class to an id

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

When I click on the class show the 'id does not return the class hide
Can you help me?
Thanks

CSS

```
    .hide{color: red}
    .show{ color: green}
```

HTML

```
<div id="prova" class="hide">
    prova
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#prova.hide").click(function()
        {

            $(this).removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("show")
        })
        $("#prova.show").click(function()
        {

            $(this).removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("hide")
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#prova").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jE9BY/)

Answer (score 1):

Your click events are not bound when you change the class.  So when you change the class, the elements do not have events associated with them anymore.

```
    $(document).on('click', "#prova.hide", function()
    {

        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("show")
    })
    $(document).on('click', "#prova.show", function()
    {

        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("hide")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

When `$("#prova.hide").click(` is called, the `click` function is only applied to those elements which match the selector **at the time the code is run.**  You should instead do something like this:

```
$("#prova").click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.hasClass("show")){
        $this.removeClass("show");
             .addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("hide");
             .addClass("show");
    }
});
```